# How to get log-end-offset of a topic in Kafka 2.1.1 by code?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I know the command  `kafka-consumer-group.sh --describe --bootstrap-server server1 --group group1` supports to get the log-end-offset, but now I want to get this of a appointed topic by code. Are there any APIs to help me get this?

Comment: I think you could easily find an answer to this question in their docs.

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any APIs to help me get this?

All Kafka scripts are just calls to Java/Scala code, so yes the API is available.

[The source code is available here](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/core/src/main/scala/kafka/admin/ConsumerGroupCommand.scala#L372-L392) and you want the `printOffsets` method there

However, you might find the [`GetOffsetShell`](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/core/src/main/scala/kafka/tools/GetOffsetShell.scala) class to be easier to read, which only gives start/end offsets of topics as compared to consumer group information